# List Duplicate Removal Issue?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a code that eliminates duplicates from a list in Python. Here it is:

```
List = [4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 6, 5]
NewList = []

for i in List:
    if List[i] not in NewList:
        NewList.append(i)

print ("Original List:", List)
print ("Reworked List:", NewList)
```

However the output is:

```
Original List: [4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 6, 5]
Reworked List: [4, 2, 3, 7, 6]
```

Why is the `1` missing from the output?

Comment: better to use `set()` for deduplication

Comment: Try printing `i` and `List[i]` inside your loop and see if you understand what is happening.

Comment: Why are yo doing `List[i]` when `i` is your element, not index?

Comment: `if i not in NewList:`

Comment: Why '1' is being removed though?

Comment: the problem is that you loop through the items in your list, which makes i first 4, then 2, then 3, but you check if the list on index 4, 2, 3 is in your list. this overcomplicates things and eventually leads to removal of 1!

Answer (score 1):

Using `set()` kills the order. You can try this :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> NewList = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(List))
```

Answer (score 0):

You missunderstood how for loops in python work. If you write `for i in List:` i will have the values from the list one after another, so in your case 4, 2, 3 ...

I assume you thought it'd be counting up.

You have several different ways of removing duplicates from lists in python that you don't need to write yourself, like converting it to a set and back to a list.

```
list(set(List))
```

Also you should read Pep8 and name your variables differently, but that just btw.

Also if you really want a loop with indices, you can use enumerate in python.

```
for idx, value in enumerate(myList):
    print(idx)
    print(myList[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing what you think it does. Your problem are these two constructs:

```
for i in List:  # 1
    if List[i]  # 2
```

1. Here you are using `i` to represent the *elements* inside the list: 4, 2, 3, ...
2. Here you are using `i` to represent the *indices* of the List: 0, 1, 2, ...

Obviously, 1. and 2. are not compatible. In short, your check is performed for a different element than the one you put in your list.

You can fix this by treating `i` consistently at both steps:

```
for i in List:
    if i not in NewList:
         NewList.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method for iterating over lists is not correct. Your code currently iterates over elements, but then *does not use* that element in your logic. Your code doesn't error because the values of your list happen also to be valid list indices.

You have a few options:

#### #1 Iterate over elements directly

Use elements of a list as you iterate over them directly:

```
NewList = []
for el in L:
    if el not in NewList:
        NewList.append(i)
```

#### #2 Iterate over list index

This is often considered anti-pattern, but is not invalid. You can iterate over the range of the size of the list and then use list indexing:

```
NewList = []
for idx in range(len(L)):
    if L[idx] not in NewList:
        NewList.append(i)
```

In both cases, notice how we avoid naming variables after built-ins. Don't use `list` or `List`, you can use `L` instead.

#### #3 unique_everseen

It's more efficient to implement hashing for O(1) lookup complexity. There is a `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the `itertools` docs, replicated in 3rd party [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique). This works by using a `seen` set and tracking items as you iterate.

```
from toolz import unique

NewList = list(unique(L))
```